# Update column through expiry in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

An user should vote for a celebrity only once in 24 hours. So I need to update a votes column in user table. What I am doing here is that I am checking whether the current user has voted. If not I am allowing him to vote.

My models are

vote.rb

```
attr_accessible :celebrity_id, :user_id
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :celebrity, counter_cache: true
```

user.rb

```
attr_accessible :email, :name, :uid, :provider, :vote
has_many :votes
```

celebrity.rb

```
attr_accessible :name, :gender, :category_id, :image, :votes_count  
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
has_many :votes
```

My controller

```
@celebrities = Celebrity.find(params[:id])    
@vote = current_user.votes.build(celebrity_id: @celebrities.id, :id => params[:vote])    
respond_to do |format|
  if current_user.vote != true
    current_user.vote = true
    current_user.save
    @vote.save        
    format.json { render json: @vote, status: :created }
  else        
    format.json { render json: @vote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
  end
end
```

But, how can I set vote column in user table to zero every 24 hrs comparing to votes table created_at time

Comment: Did you gave a try to `cron`?

Comment: Nope, I really don't have any idea as I am new to rails

Comment: Have a look at `rufus-scheduler` or `whenever` gem. It might help you

Comment: Your logic here makes no sense. In `votes_controller#create` you want to check if the last vote is older than 24 hours and allow creating a new vote or not. No updating of columns or scheduling is required.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel 'if @vote.created_at > Time.now - 24.hours' it says 'undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass' error. what should I do now

Comment: http://pastie.org/10406890 can anyone help me here, I am getting this error 'undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: If you don't know what to do with an error like that you really need to learn how to debug your code or way forward will be extremely painful. Try opening `rails console` load your vote (however you do it) and check if it's valid, if it has created_at, etc, etc. This is a simple problem and you need to be able to find a solution yourself.